# Check APEX exception type

Tags: apex, exception

I'm looking to check what type of exception is retruned in the following code snippet.
I'm not sure exactly how to do it though, or if it's even possible.

```
try {
    //SOME LOGIC
} catch (exception ex) {
    System.debug(//EXCEPTION TYPE);
}
```

Would anyone have any suggestions or advice??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [`getTypeName()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) method on the Exception class that you can use.  It will output the actual instance's type.

Example 1:

```
try {
    //SOME LOGIC
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getTypeName()); 
}
```

Example 2:

```
Exception e = new MyCustomException();
System.debug(e.getTypeName()); 
// outputs 'MyCustomException', not 'Exception'.
```

Comment: Can also make use of 'e instanceof DmlException' etc

Comment: You can also catch specific exceptions, as in `catch(DmlException e) { ... } catch(NoAccessException e) { ... } ... `

Comment: Excellent, cheers guys!